# Python-VLC Errors When Opening Video File and Skipping Video Playback Position

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, vlc, libvlc, python-vlc

I'm working on a project making a semi-randomized video player on the Raspberry Pi 4 (64-bit OS with Desktop) using Python-VLC. I have a proof of concept working, but I get some strange error messages whenever I open a new video file or skip the playback position.

Here is the error when a new file is opened:

```
[0000007f680013e0] mmal_xsplitter vout display error: Failed to open Xsplitter:opengles2 module
[0000007f680013e0] mmal_xsplitter vout display error: Failed to open Xsplitter:mmal_vout module
[0000007f6c013b10] avcodec decoder: Using DRM Video Accel for hardware decoding
```

Here is the error when I skip playback position:

```
[0000007f6c013b10] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 315848867: no reference clock
[0000007f6c013b10] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
```

The program seems to work in spite of these, but there's some minor lag I'd like to get rid of, and I want to make sure a problem doesn't arise from these errors piling up since I plan on running this program continuously for long periods of time.

Can anyone help explain what these errors mean and how I can get rid of them?

Here is the code I am using:

```
import vlc
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import pygame
import random

def mute():
    media_player.get_media_player().audio_set_volume(0)


opin = 2
ipin = 4

pos = [0, 0]
index = 0


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(opin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(ipin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

player = vlc.Instance("--no-xlib")

media_player = player.media_list_player_new()

media_list = player.media_list_new()

media = player.media_new("/home/hhaudio/Desktop/Malice.mp4")
media_list.add_media(media)

media = player.media_new("/home/hhaudio/Desktop/Croc.mp4")
media_list.add_media(media)

media_player.set_media_list(media_list)
media_player.play_item_at_index(0)

mute()

print("hello!")

nextvid = 1

while True:

    if GPIO.input(opin) == 0:
        print("exit")
        exit()
        break
    if GPIO.input(ipin) == 0 and nextvid == 1:
        print("ipin")
        media_player.get_media_player().set_position(random.random())
    nextvid = GPIO.input(ipin)
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

As a bonus, are there any recommendations y'all can give about how I could optimize things to make playback faster with VLC settings, etc?

Ran my program, according to my understanding of the VLC documentation. Works but is slightly laggy and throws errors.

Comment: There is a discussion here https://github.com/RPi-Distro/vlc/issues/30 that might help. The suggestion is add `--vout mmal_vout` to the instance options

Comment: When I add --vout mmal_vout to the options the program fails altogether. I get an error:

"main video output error: video output creation failed"
"main decoder error: failed to create video output"